# How to use hashtable and bucket hashing

Tags: java, hashtable

So recently I have been trying to practice with hashing and using linkedlists in a table to store values. I understand the concept but I am having trouble putting it into practice and can't seem to find what I'm looking for online.

For example:
Let's say I wanted to use a hashtable to store things like for a computer such as the monitor, mouse, etc. I would want methods such as:

```
boolean addMonitor(String id, String description, double price, int units, String size)

boolean addMouse(String id, String description, double price, int units, int buttons)
```

I don't understand how to use these methods to store them in a hashtable. I would obviously like to use other methods to access and change the values within each later too. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if its name says "table", HashTable is not like a "database table" where you have columns, and each column store values... it seems that you want use hashtable as a database table.

Hashtable store objects! So your methods should look better like this:

```
public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ItemStore store;
        Monitor monitor;
        Mouse mouse;

        store = new ItemStore();
        monitor = new Monitor();
        monitor.id = 2;
        monitor.price = 6;

        mouse = new Mouse();
        mouse.id = 7;
        mouse.buttons = 3;

        store.addItem(monitor);
        store.addItem(mouse);

        System.out.println(store.getItem(2).price);   // = 6
        System.out.println(((Monitor) store.getItem(2)).dpi);
        System.out.println(((Mouse) store.getItem(7)).buttons); //Downcasting ... = 3
    }
    public static class Item {
       String id;
       String description;
       int price;
       // common attributes here!
    }

    public static class Monitor extends Item {
        private int dpi;
       // monitor particular atributes here!!
    }

    public static class Mouse extends Item {
        private int buttons;
        // mouse particular attributes here!!!
    }


    public static class ItemStore {
       private Hashtable<String, Item> table = new HashTable<>();

       public boolean addItem(Item item) {
           this.table.put(item.getId(), item);
       }

       public Item getItem(String id) {
           return this.table.get(id);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: With a hashtable, I thought that you could store an object that would point to a linked list so that you could have say one object but that object has a bunch of other data?

Comment: Yes, you can... my example (I believe) demostrate that, but in a more simplified (encapsulated) way!! ...

Comment: Alright, could I then use the method I provided at the top but when storing only use the ID to compare?

Comment: Yes, the ID should be the key store/retrieve objects (whatever they are) from the hashtable. But beware, ID is associated to only one object at the time (I hope that you are not planning to do something like this: `hashtable.put(Id, description); hashtable.put(id, price); ...` if you do that, you wil overwrite the previous insert value associated to the given ID!

Comment: What I am trying to do is have a single hashtable that stores an ID and that is the key. But I still want the rest of the information to be related to that key. So like I can call the ID of the monitor and then have access to the price, size, etc. But still store the ID of the mouse in the same hashtable even though they do not have the same extra information.

Comment: For that, you can do something like the code I give you. Define the common properties in BaseClass, let's called Item, and extend the BaseClass to represent Monitor/Mouse particular details... the map should store Items (monitors, mouses, etc)... when retrieving the data, the map will return Items... to get monitor/mouse behaviour, you must use `instanceof` and do a DownCasting....

Comment: Could you show me what exactly you mean? For some reason this is just going over my head. I can't seem to understand.